# How to save high score in c++?

Tags: c++

I create a small car game. But I can't save high score which is used next time when I play game again . So that I compare score. I using c++ language and `#include<graphics.h>` header file?

Please help me? How to save score in graphics mode?

Comment: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/basic-file-io/

Comment: The way you save a score is the same whether you are in graphics mode or not. You write the score to a file on your local file system. Then next time your program runs you can read that file back again.

Comment: @john or you send a message to a(nother) computer over the internet with the value of the score, and ask that computer to send you the list of high scores when you want to show them

Comment: Side note: `<graphics.h>` is a **very old** graphics library for MS-DOS. True, it has the advantage for a beginner of being simple. But you cannot write a serious game nowadays with this prehistoric library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me an easy solution is, as others users told to you, to store it using the file system, so the next time you need to get the highest score you can take it with ease, let me write you an example:

```
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
fstream fs;
fs.open("score.txt",iOS::app);//ios::app is to append the text to the end of the file
fs<<[new highest score];
fs.close();
```

In case you only want to save one record, open the file using trunc to erase all elements and then you can write it down :

```
void clear_file(std::string path){
   fstream fs;
   fs.open(path, ios::trunc);
   fs.close();
}
```

Check [Cplusplus fstream](https://cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) for further information, hope it helps you out